# Platform 1.8 login differences between localhost and 127.0.0.1

Tags: admin, magento-1.8, login

Will there be any difference if I login to my Magento admin panel by `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Afaik was there a problem in the past with urls which do not contain a `.`. therefore maybe there is a problem with localhost. But beside this no, I don't think so

Comment: I working this stuff I think there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found that using localhost just won't work. Why this restriction exists is beyond me. You can either use the IP or create a dummy domain entry in your hosts file to use something like

```
127.0.0.1     dummy.magento
```

Then when you type in http://dummy.magento/admin (if your store is installed at root) it will open the admin login page.

Remember to change these core_config_data values

```
web/unsecure/base_url 
web/secure/base_url
```

BTW, I think this has been an issue since at least 1.4